# Date range marker algorithm using with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sports project.

```
Country     League      StartDate           EndDate
------------------------------------------------------------
USA         UPA         10.10.2015          13.06.2018
```

When I use below code I am getting result as above.

```
SELECT Country
      ,League
      ,MIN(MatchDateTimeUtc) AS StartDate
      ,MAX(MatchDateTimeUtc) AS EndDate
FROM Games
WHERE Country = 'USA'
GROUP BY Country
        ,League
```

I need to mark season by date range. 
But date ranges is not constant. 
I mean start or end date of each league is not certain. 
Start or end date of any league may change. 
Only country and league fields are constant. 
For example, actually above results has got 3 season.
My expected result as below.

```
Country     League      StartDate           EndDate
------------------------------------------------------------
USA         UPA         10.10.2015          09.04.2016
USA         UPA         22.10.2016          11.05.2017
USA         UPA         30.09.2017          13.06.2018
```

Is there any smart logic for that?

Comment: You need to add another logic (like for example a season is at most X months long, or always starts at Spring) or it will be impossible to know each season start and end accurately.

Comment: Every season has got consecutive rest date range min 2 months. I thought may be I can find a way from that. But I could not find.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need some more input about how to differentiate games from different seasons.

The simplest example is to make restrictive assumptions, for example that "all season games are on the same year and each year contains games only from 1 season". In which case you can add grouping by year as wel, ex: `year(startDate)`:

```
SELECT Country, 
    League, 
    MIN(MatchDateTimeUtc) AS StartDate, 
    MAX(MatchDateTimeUtc) AS EndDate 
FROM Games 
WHERE Country = 'USA' 
GROUP BY Country, League, year(startDate)
```

If no such simple convention about season can be fixed, then you need to introduce another table for league_seasons and join the league_season table for grouping.

---

As "season" is by OP comments defined **by the length of gap between the games**, then you could use a query like this:

```
;with removedDuplicates as (
    select distinct * from games    
),
gamesWithSeasonNumber AS (
    select g.*,
    SUM(
        case when not exists (
            select 1 from removedDuplicates previousG
            where previousG.Country = g.Country and previousG.League = g.League
                and previousG.MatchDateTimeUtc < g.MatchDateTimeUtc
                and (DATEDIFF(d, previousG.MatchDateTimeUtc, g.MatchDateTimeUtc) < 60)) 
            then 1 else 0 
        end) 
    OVER(Partition By Country, LEague ORDER BY MatchDateTimeUtc) as SeasonNumber
    from removedDuplicates g
)
select Country, League, min(MatchDateTimeUtc) as startDate, max(MatchDateTimeUtc) as EndDate
from gamesWithSeasonNumber 
group by Country, League, SeasonNumber
```

The key parts to this solution are:

1. We know which games are season start games - they must not have any games starting too close before them (i'm assuming 60 days here as the minimal off-season length)
2. if you order by game date, then cumulative SUM of starter games gives a season number to all rows.  [See OVER-clause in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
3. Once you have season number, it's trivial group by for date min/maxing.

[Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to keep the query readable as step-by-step.

Comment: Every season has got consecutive rest date range min 2 months. I thought may be I can find a way from that. But I could not find.

Comment: Added solution by gap length. Something like this?

Comment: This solutions query time is so long but may be I can create a different table for join with this query's results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, the season can be calculated by subtracting 8 months and using the year:

```
SELECT Country, League, 
       MIN(MatchDateTimeUtc) AS StartDate, 
       MAX(MatchDateTimeUtc) AS EndDate 
FROM Games 
WHERE Country = 'USA' 
GROUP BY Country, League, 
      YEAR(DATEADD(month, -8, startDate));
```

That should work for any seasons that start in September - December and end before August.  All your data supports this definition.  If you have more detailed data, I would really suggest that you ask another question, with a better definition of "season" and better examples of *raw* data.

Comment: Yes big part of data usage period about 8 months. But sometimes not. Because of tournaments. I think  algorithm should run from not usage period. I mean I must mark empty consecutive  days about 2 months for separating data.

Comment: @Kerberos . . . Then ask a new question and provide appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: This solution is not universal as a general "game season" may as well start in Feb and end in Nov.